# Spring Batch SkippListener not printing logs

Tags: spring, log4j, spring-batch

I am not sure why the SkipListener is not printing the simple logs. I want to log the skipped records into a separate log file and I am thinking I can use MDC.put(). But I am not even able to print a log in console not sure what is happening. I think I am missing something. A help would be really appreciated. I even tried with generic Exception.class for testing but still not doing anything. Here is my code;

**BtachConfiguration**

```
        @EnableBatchProcessing
        public class BatchConfiguration {
            static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger(BatchConfiguration.class);
            @Autowired
            public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

            @Autowired
            public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

            @Autowired
            public DataSource dataSource;

            @Bean
            public Job loadUserJob() {
                return jobBuilderFactory.get("loadUserJob")
                        .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                        .start(loadUsersStep())
                        .listener(new JobLoggerListener())
                        .build();
            }
                   
            @Bean
            public Step loadUsersStep() {
                return stepBuilderFactory.get("loadUsersStep")
                        .<UserInfo, UserInfoDTO> chunk(10)
                        .reader(reader())
                        .processor(UserInfoItemProcessor())
                        .writer(writer())
                        .faultTolerant()
                        .skipLimit(3)
                        .skip(Exception.class)
                        //.skip(UserNotFoundException.class)                        
                        .listener(new StepStartStopListener())
                        .listener(new LoadDataSkipListener())
                        .build();
            }

            @Bean
            public FlatFileItemReader<UserInfo> reader() {
                
                return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<UserInfo>()
                        .name("reader")
                        .delimited()
                        .names(new String[] { 
                                    "first_name",
                                    "last_name",
                                    "email"})
                        .targetType(UserInfo.class)
                        .resource(new ClassPathResource("userinfo_file.csv"))
                        .build();
            }


            @Bean
            public UserInfoItemProcessor UserInfoItemProcessor() {
                return new UserInfoItemProcessor();
            }
            
            @Bean
            public JdbcBatchItemWriter<UserInfoDTO> writer() {
                JdbcBatchItemWriter<UserInfoDTO> writer = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<UserInfoDTO>();
                writer.setItemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<>());
                writer.setSql("INSERT INTO db1.userinfo "
                        + "(first_name,last_name,email) " +
                        "VALUES (:firstName, :lastName,:email)");
                writer.setDataSource(dataSource);
                return writer;
            }
        }
```

**SkipListener Class**

```
        public class LoadDataSkipListener implements SkipListener<UserInfoDTO, UserInfoDTO>{
            
            public static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger(LoadDataSkipListener.class);

            @Override
            public void onSkipInRead(Throwable t) {
                LOG.info("ItemWriter:  ");
                
                
            }

            @Override
            public void onSkipInWrite(UserInfoDTO item, Throwable t) {
                LOG.info(">>> onSkipInWrite <<<");

        //      MDC.put("skipped_users", String.valueOf(item.getUserId())); // I want to log skipped user ids on write
                
            }

            @Override
            public void onSkipInProcess(UserInfoDTO item, Throwable t) {
                LOG.info(">>> onSkipInProcess<<< ");
                
            }
        }
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db1?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.schema=classpath:/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-mysql.sql
spring.batch.initialize-schema=always
spring.datasource.initialize=true

#logging.file={log-name}.log --> WIll this write into a new file ??
```

Just want to know

1. Why its not even printing in console ?
2. Can the commented MDC be used to write to a new file ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1. Probably wrong log level, 2 no. Just create a skiplistener that writes to a file don't abuse logging for that. I would also so that your generics are wrong shouldn't that be `<UserInfo, UserInfoDto>` just like your step configuration.

Comment: Thank you very much ! I think its working and its a mistake that I missed. But appreciate more on logging suggestion. I think I would use a normal file writer logic.

Comment: IIRC there is even a sample in the Spring Batch samples that writes skipped lines to a file , you can probably just look at that.

Comment: I was just trying but could not find, can you please share the link? Thank you!

Comment: I was apparentlhy wrong, there is the `ErrorTasklet` that writes a small report based on the execution context. But not a `SkipListener` that writes items to a csv. Although I could swear that such a sample did exist.

Comment: @M.Deinum you are probably referring to this: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-samples/src/test/java/org/springframework/batch/sample/common/SkipCheckingListener.java? The sample is described here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/tree/master/spring-batch-samples#skip-sample.

Comment: @Thomson: Are you sure that an exception is thrown and that your listener is called? And as Marten said, I would use a regular file writer instead of logging for skipped items. BTW, here is another complete example of how to write skipped items to a file: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/1912#issuecomment-575129041